# Convert Stringified ID to ObjectId in Monogdb in scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

How can we convert Id in string form to Mongodb ObjectId in scala?
For example

```
"_id": "57d90fde5b0000cd3cbdfcdf"
```

How to convert _id to ObjectId("57d90fde5b0000cd3cbdfcdf")

Comment: are you using reactive mongo library?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply import the MongoDB Java API dependency and use the ObjectId constructor as you'd do in Java too.

For example:

```
val id: ObjectId = new ObjectId("57d90fde5b0000cd3cbdfcdf");
```